# Preserve a single existing file, but install all other in a directory tree in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a application in beta testing phase. It has application files, and a database (`.db`) file, which I would like to keep and not replace.

Let's assume I provided a version 1.0 to my clients, and they installed it. Now I have version 1.1 that has some changes in the application files, but not in the db.

How can I instruct Inno Setup to preserve that one file, and for the rest of them just replace?

```
[Files]
Source: "D:\nw\testfile.db"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: uninsneveruninstall onlyifdoesntexist
Source: "D:\nw\*"; Excludes: "\node_modules\"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

With this script file, the `testfile.db` is always overwritten with the new version.

My goal is to preserve the `testfile.db` during the new installation.

> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.630   -- File entry --
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.630   Dest filename: C:\Complexity tool\testfile.txt
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.631   Time stamp of our file: 2016-06-06 09:41:08.000
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.631   Dest file exists.
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.631   Time stamp of existing file: 2016-06-06 09:41:08.000
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.631   Version of our file: (none)
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.631   Version of existing file: (none)
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.631   Installing the file.
> 2016-06-06 13:36:21.632   Successfully installed the file.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that while the file is probably not installed by the first entry `D:\nw\testfile.db`, it is installed by the second wildcard entry `D:\nw\*`.

You have to add `onlyifdoesntexist` even to the wildcard entry. Or if you need to overwrite all the other files, even if they exist, explicitly exclude the `testfile.db` file from the wildcard entry:

```
Source: "D:\nw\testfile.db"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: uninsneveruninstall onlyifdoesntexist
Source: "D:\nw\*"; Excludes: "\node_modules\,\testfile.db"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```